# What is the appropriate term for the "string splitting" problem?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, strings

To be clear, I didn't hear of this in any particular venue, and so can't point you to one.

Two variants that I can bring you:

1. String spitting

   > Given a string (sequence of elements), and a function that takes a substring and returns a score/penalty. Overall score is the product of scores of chosen split.
   >
   > Find the optimal way to split the string into consecutive, non-overlapping substring to maximize the score.
2. String folding

   > Given the same as (1).
   >
   > Also given a function that takes two substring and an edge (head-head, head-tail, etc.) specifying how the substrings will connect, returns a score.
   >
   > Find the optimal way to "fold" the string. Any two "elbows" (or folding points) can be made to touch. No length limitations (substring length is not geometrically motivated).

I haven't been able to find mentions of "optimizing string splitting" online. So I'm doubting it might be more specialized than I'd thought.

Comment: The 'string splitting' operation on a string is the same as deciding on line-breaks in a piece of text. The objective function is usually global in that case, and not local as you describe here. There is quite some literature on line-breaking, perhaps searching for "line breaking algorithm" or something similar will help.

Comment: Can you clarify how the individual scores of the sub-strings in (1) are combined to a total score? Is it simply a summation, or do you take a sum of squares or something more involved?

Comment: @Discretelizard - Line breaking looks very interesting, thanks! ; I added a bit on the total score. You can choose something else if it's interesting to handle. Mine is simply the product of the probabilities of the chosen split.